# blocking a specific USB device

Tags: usb, blocking

Is there a way to block a specific USB from my machine? I don't have access to it physically anymore and thus why I need blocking. It is still being used by some individual whose identity is currently unknown.

The only information I currently possess is its serial number, vendor id, product id.

Edit:
Windows 10 64bit

Comment: And the OS is…?

Comment: Linux: Write an *udev* rule to ignore it.

Comment: Since OS is unknown then universal way for any OS is to ask anybody on premises to fill USB sockets with hot glue gun

Comment: Ugh I apologize for not stating with OS. Windows 10 64bit